# Debug.Log() A 2D array from a custom class to main class

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here's my code.

**CustomClass.cs**

```
 class ScoreBoard(){

 private int m_lastCnt;

 public ScoreBoard{
     m_lastCnt = 0;
 }

 public void makeBoard(string history) {

 string[] arrPartStr = history.Split(',');

    int[] arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];

    for (int c = 0; c < arrPart.Length; c++)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'P') temp = 100;
        else if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'B') temp = 200;
        else temp = 300;
        if (arrPartStr[c][1] == 'P') temp += 10;
        if (arrPartStr[c][2] == 'P') temp += 1;

        arrPart[c] = temp;
    }

    //var strTmp : String = strData;    
    //strTmp = "311|101|211|211|211|211|211|211|211|211|111|111|111|111|111|111|111|111|111"
    //strTmp = strData.replace(/:/g,"");    

    int[,] arrTmp = new int[6100, 104];
 }
 }
```

**Main Class** i call the void method like this

```
ScoreBoard sb = ScoreBoard();
string history = "s  ,o  ,m  ,e  ,s  ,t  ,r  ,i  ,n  ,g";
private void Start(){
     sb.makeBoard(history);
}
```

How can i print my 2D array in my console?

I tried doing it like the `for(int row){for(int col){}}` but its not working i don't know why

Comment: what is inside your scoreboard class ?

Comment: @Prany Just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrTmp.GetLength(1); j++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arrTmp.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    var msg = "[" + i.ToString() + ", " + j.ToString() + "] = " + arrTmp[i, j].ToString();
    Debug.Log(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work as i said on the last part . Geez I'm reall doing something very wrong.

Comment: Hey @TheGinxx009, in the future, just include those pieces that don't work, even though you think they should. It helps us to narrow down the problem a lot quicker if we know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to display:)

**CustomClass.cs**

```
int[,] arrTmp = new int[104, 6];
public int[,] GetBoard(){ return arrTmp }
```

**MainClass.cs**

```
int[,] arrayBigRoad = bsb.GetBoard();
for (int j = 0; j < arrTmp.GetLength(1); j++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arrTmp.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    var msg = "[" + i.ToString() + ", " + j.ToString() + "] = " + arrTmp[i, j].ToString();
    Debug.Log(msg);
  }
}
```

Thanks though Rodrigo . I'll mark yours as an answer

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues sorry about that . I totally forgot